# How do you say „I had to help with the cooking“?

Tags: english-to-german

Can you say „ich musste beim Kochen helfen.“?
Is it also correct to say „Ich habe beim Kochen helfen müssen“? 
Which one is better?

Comment: Which one is better? - The first one.

Comment: @user41319: How would you describe the "not knowing whats better"? What makes you feel unsure about this or that?  @ folks: why the close votes? I see no comment about it while I see attempt of the OP with giving two translations.

Answer (score 3):

Past tense (Präteritum): "Ich musste beim Kochen helfen."

Perfect tense (Perfekt): "Ich habe beim Kochen helfen müssen."

Past perfect (Plusquamperfekt): "Ich hatte beim Kochen helfen müssen."

**So both of your translations are correct, but typically in a conversation you'd go by the past tense.**

Comment: Ummm... that depends. In the south, Präteritum is rarely used in spoken language. I think we even have a few Q/As on that somewhere on the site. You may want to start [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=Perfekt+Präteritum+).

Comment: @Stephie I am from the south and I can confirm that Perfekt (typically mixed with dialect) is more common here. But also the opinion that this is some kind of "Bauernsprache". People trying hard to use Präteritum to tell the world they're well educated. Maybe this situation affects my answer, but I'd never say "Ich habe beim Kochen helfen müssen".

Comment: I would. Without batting an eye. I wouldn’t _write_ it, but people (yes, including friends and colleagues with a PhD, working in an international company with Swabian roots) would be giving me strange looks for using the Präteritum. Especially in an informal context like small talk.